# Link a compiled .res file with CMake

Tags: c++, resources, cmake

I'm trying to link a compiled .res file with cmake but I can't seem to find out much info on how to do it.

The closest I have got is

```
SET(RESOURCE_FILE resource.res)

file(GLOB src_files 
"src/*.h"
"src/*.cpp"
"${RESOURCE_FILE}"
)

add_executable(exename  ${src_files})
```

and then manually linking the .res file thru the IDE (i.e. in visual studio dropping the .res file in the Linker additional dependencies).  This means I have to reset the additional dependency every time I change the cmake file.  Surely there is a better way than this

Forgive my inexperience with cmake, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `target_link_libraries(exename ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resource.res)` work for you?

Comment: no I've tried that. the IDE just tells me

    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'resource.res.lib'

Comment: Even if you pass the full path (i.e. ensure you have `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resource.res`, not just `resource.res`) in the `target_link_libraries` call?

Comment: yeah it gives the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default lib extension is a bit sticky one, but you can do as follows:

```
# ...
ADD_EXECUTABLE( FOO ${FOO_SRCS} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( FOO ${FOO_LIBS} )
SET( FOO_LINKFLAGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.res )
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( FOO PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${FOO_LINKFLAGS} )
```

which would show up in MSVC as additional [linker] options (instead of dependencies). Hope that helps.

If there are other `LINK_FLAGS` defined, you may need to first store them in the `FOO_LINKFLAGS` and then append new ones.

Comment: It works! Thanks, I've been trying for ages to try and get this working :)

Answer (score 5):

In more modern CMake, this became quite simple: Just add your resource file to the list of source files.

```
target_sources(mybinary PRIVATE "src/main.cpp" "resources/mybinary.rc")
```

For my CMake project, using Visual Studio 2022, compiling the resources file with rc and linking it works like a charm.

Comment: For the record: it also works fine with MinGW